# How to deselect a column from a chart or graph in iWork Numbers?

Tags: iwork-numbers

When I select a chart and press **Edit Data References** it shows the columns I've selected. How do I unselect or delete a column or some cells?

In my first column of data I want to deselect the first 20 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it. 
You have to:

1. Select the chart and click Edit Data References.
2. Select the graph that has the data (click on the line) or select the tab at the top of the column. This shows specific properties for the series in the panel on the right.
    [image]
    [image]
3. Select the series section and then in the data section, in the value field, delete the data by pressing the backspace or delete key until it's an empty text input.  or press delete/backspace once and the whole statement is selected.
    A bluish box with resize handles appear in the table that you can use to select the columns you want...
    [image]
    [image]
    To delete the data you have to select the line or graph in the chart and hit the delete key. If you can't see it or there is only one cell selected, click on the tab at the top of the column and then wait a second and then hit the delete key.
4. When the bluish selection rectangle appears use the drag anchors to select the cells that you want to use.
5. Click green OK checkbox in the function pop up menu

   [image]